# laravel Lazy Eager Loading with orderBy related model

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5

I need to lazy eager load some related models with custom order. Something like:

```
$season->load(['championships' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('country', 'desc');
}]);
```

But the problem is that championships do not have country property. In Championship model I use getCountryAttribute function:

```
public function getCountryAttribute()
{
    return $this->masterChampionship->country;
}

public function masterChampionship()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\MasterChampionship');
}
```

And I get next results:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'country' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `championships` where `championships`.`season_id` in (41) order by `country` desc)
```

If i don't use **load** in controller and access championships from blade template

```
@foreach($season->championships->sortBy('country') as $championship)
    ....
@endforeach
```

everything works fine. But I want to cleanup template and move logic to controller. Is there any possibility to solve my case using built-in laravel features, without building custom BD query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youll have to change the table names, as I don't know what they are, but I think this would work:

```
$season->load(['championships' => function($query){

    $query->select('championships.*')
        ->join('master_championships', 'championships.master_championships_id', '=', 'master_championships.id')
        ->orderBy('master_championships.country', 'desc');

}]);
```

I don't think you can order the query without using a join, seeing as you have to access the third table to get the `country` attribute.  You may save a bunch of queries from hitting the database if you do

```
$season->load(['championships','championships.masterChampionships']);
```

Comment: everything works. Some mistakes with table and columns names
championships.master_championships_id -> championships.master_championship_id
master_championships.country -> master_championships.country_id